# want to improve regulare expression

Tags: php, regex

i have implemented regular expression which matches following

```
GET[name]
GET[name]^
POST[name]
SEGMENT[name]^
```

my regular expression

```
preg_match("/(GET|POST|SEGMENT)\[(.*?)\](\^){0,1}/i", $value, $match);
```

this also matching `GET[name]Roger`

if caret **^** is present then it should match preceeding string otherwise not

**Example :**
 `GET[name]^Roger`  must return true

`GET[name]Roger`  must return false

please let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
preg_match("/^(GET|POST|SEGMENT)\[(.*?)\](\^.*)?$/i", $value, $match);
```

This will match `GET[name]Roger` but will NOT match `GET[name]Roger`

Comment: last matching pattern not returning `^` and `Roger` in `$match`

Comment: see edited code, basically remove `?:` from last matching group.